# Using the Jones polynomial, determine which of the following links are equivalent or inequivalent?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

[Struggling to start this as not sure if to use skien relation or work out the writhe and kauffman brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J7oG.png)

Comment: I think I might use the skein relations and carefully keep track of which diagrams I've already seen, changing crossings to relate each link to the others.  The full Kauffman bracket would take 64 expansions, which a computer can do easily, but which a human might not want to do...